# Nested styles in IE overridden my same names on CSS sprites

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, stylesheet, sprite

I have some CSS sprites to change the image when you hover over them. I then have some jQuery which adds a class to the element if you mouseenter over it (thus changing the background image) and fades it in. This is because a want a smooth transition between the hover images, rather than the straight cut between one image to another.

In Chrome and Firefox the roll over and fade effects work fine. However, in IE the last style with the same name gets applied to the element with the incorrect background image.

For the example below #main a.style2.active is the background image that is shown for style1. I'm assuming this is because the last 'active' class is the one IE picks up on.

How can I restructure my styles so that style1 gets the #main a.style1.active background image applied to it?

```
    <style media="screen">
    #main{
        width: 985px;
        height: 600px;
        background: url(../img/my.jpg);
        margin: 0px; 
        padding: 0;
        position: absolute;
    }
    #main li {
        margin: 0; 
        padding: 0; 
        list-style: none;
    }

    #main a.style1 { left: 0px; width: 337px; top: 0px; height: 600px; position: absolute; }
    #main a.style1.active { background: url(../img/my.jpg) -0px -600px; }

    #main a.style2 { left: 337px; width: 330px; top: 0px; height: 600px; position: absolute; }
    #main a.style2.active { background: url(../img/my.jpg) -337px -600px; }
    </style>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('.elem').mouseenter(function(){
            if ($(this).is(':animated')){
                $(this).stop();
            }
            $(this).hide().addClass('active').fadeTo(750,1);
        });

        $('.elem').mouseleave(function(){
            if ($(this).is(':animated')){
                $(this).stop();
            }
            $(this).fadeTo(750, 0, function(){
                $(this).removeClass('active').css({'filter' : 'none', 'display' : 'block'});
            });
        });

});
    </script>

    <ul id="main">
      <li><a class="elem style1" href="#"></a></li>
      <li><a class="elem style2" href="#"></a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Not sure which version of IE you have having problems with but IE6 doesn't support multiple class selectors.

Answer (score 2):

I think something like this should work:

```
#main a.style1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 337px;
    height: 600px;
    background-position: -0px -600px;
}

#main a.style2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 337px;
    width: 330px;
    height: 600px;
    background-position: -337px -600px;
}

#main a.active {
    background-image: url(../img/my.jpg);
}
```